# Notepad++ quick style token shortcuts

Tags: search, styles, notepad++, highlight, markers

I use Notepad++ a lot but there's one feature I miss: a quick search/marker toolbar.

Another great editor that has this feature is the EmEditor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGx9N.png

On that toolbar we can click to highlight all the results of that search expression on the document and at the same time move to the next result (F3-like behavior). Holding the Shift key while clicking the marker moves to the previous results (Shift-F3 like behavior).

That is a great help to navigate on huge log files.

Since Notepad++ has style tokens and basic search shortcuts, my question is: is there any plugin that accomplishes that result (configurable toolbar shortcuts to highlight all results and navigate to the next/previous result, only a click away)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In the Find window, select the **Mark** tab. Ensure **Bookmark lines** is selected. Enter the search criteria, including regular expressions if desired. Click **Mark All**. Use the **F2** key to step through the marked lines. The **F2** means move to next bookmark and **Shift-F2** means move to previous bookmark. These are just two of many bookmark operations available via Menu => **Search** => **Bookmark**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that Notepad++ already has the individual features implemented. My goal is to have that functionality gathered in a single feature like the markers on the EmEditor. The steps you describe force me to type every token before each search. That's time consuming, error prone and not practical when handling more than a couple of tokens.

Comment: @nelson.t.cunha  Have you tried Incremental Search (**Ctrl+Alt+I**) in Notepad++ and then using the forward and backward icons?

Comment: Hi @AdrianHHH thank you for your reply. Yes, I know the Incremental Search feature. Please note that my goal is automate the tasks that I apply a lot of times on my log files: for a few tokens, Stylize all occurrences with a different color per token and quickly Find-Next/Find-Previous. Since incremental search expects me to type the search token, it doesn't help me with those tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Go into settings--> shortcut mapper and you should be able to create shortcut here.

Answer (score 0):

By default no shortcut key for that.
Create one from

> Settings -> Style Configurator

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. Create a shortcut key for what, specifically? Also, I don't see how you can create shortcuts on the "Style Configurator" screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the shortcuts in Settings->Shortcut Mapper , filter by "style" for style token search & apply shortcuts

by default for style token 1,
search next is CTRL + 1 , previous is CTRL + SHIFT + 1

you can map your custom style tokens in Shortcut Mapper
also note there are many shortcuts that have no maps by default but you can map a new shortcut yourself (like applying style token is unmapped by default, only search is mapped)